# Invisible Video Watermark

Tags: matlab, video, video-watermarking

I am doing a project in invisible Video Watermarking in Matlab. But I don't know where to start and how to do it. All I can find is visible watermark on the video. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the term 'steganographic' in this context it may help - steganography is basically hiding one message in another and some of the academic and basic building block material may favour this term. Some of the video techniques will be strongly related to single image techniques also as the hidden image or watermark, or part of the watermark more commonly, is hidden in individual frames within the video.

Some examples in the MathLab domain:

- https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41326-steganography-using-lsb-substitution?requestedDomain=true
- https://sites.google.com/site/cs534steganographyproject/home/matlab-code-and-examples